# Connection manager in SSIS pointing to incorrect database

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am building a SSIS package using SSDT 2015. I have created two connection managers. One pointing to A database and other to B database. The second manager  connection manager seems loosing the reference to the database every time i open the solution. It points to A instead of B. I am saving every time but it doesn't seem to remember the save.

Has anybody faced this issue ?

[image]

Properties window of the connection manager

[image]

Expressions editor

[image]

Comment: Not really. For B, did you try "test connection" ? What happens when you run the package ? Also, build the solution once, after saving(might not really be helpful)

Comment: Its hard to tell. Could you provide some images on how its properties are? Also is it set to work offline ?

Comment: Click the Expressions [+] item there on the connection manager and if there are items listed, please add another screenshot

Comment: posted the expressions screenshot. Nothing in there

Comment: Oh, umm right click on the main canvas in your control flow area and you should see a value for Package Configurations. When that opens up, are there values in there or is it blank?

Comment: Yup there were values and the connectionstring was pointing to the database A instead of B. I have anyways disabled the package configurations and it works fine. I think i would anyways not need this package configurations any more and use parameters to set the enviornment values for my packages